# Modify values in 1 column based on the value in another column in the previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and 4 row,

```
import pandas as pd
df_ticker = pd.DataFrame({'Min_val': [22382,37876,46717,62247], 'Max_val': [36901,46716,62045,182727],
               'Ticker':['$','$$','$$$','$$$$']})
df_ticker
```

Sample input:

[image]

I want to modify Min value in the dataframe so than at index 1 min_val=max_val(at index 0) + 1.

Output:

[image]

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Huh? Your input and output are identical.

Comment: No, In output I want the min_val  at index 1 =max_val(at index 0) + 1.

Answer (score 1):

The shift function works. To keep the Min_val in the first column you can just specify `1:` with the `loc` function, otherwise it would set the first row to `NaN`

```
df_ticker.loc[1:,'Min_val'] = df_ticker['Max_val'].shift(1) + 1
```